# How to fill a section of a column with already existing values corresponding to another column in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, tapply

I'm working on some cleaning data for some flight trajectories and 'callsign' is a required field that I need to have filled in.

[Section of the csv I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPrby.png)

The data I'm working with has almost 300000 rows and this issue of blank callsigns is quite repetitive. Is there any way I can fill these callsigns in based on their corresponding icao24 identification numbers?

I've tried using a tapply() function for sectioning off the data on the basis of their icao24 number and applying a function to each chunk ie.

```
tapply(myDF$callsign, myDF$icao24, ...)
```

But I can't seem to understand what 'function' I would be applying to each section because they are named differently. Would I need to use some sort of loop iterating over each section with a tapply() applied to each section?

Answer (score 0):

If the values are blank (`""`), then do a group_by 'icao24' and `replace` the elements that are `""` with the `first` element of non-blank 'callsign'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1%>%
   group_by(icao24) %>%
   mutate(callsign = replace(callsign, callsign == "", 
            first(callsign[callsign != ""])))
```

---

Another option is `fill` after converting the blank to `NA`

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
   mutate(callsign = na_if(callsign, "")) %>%
   group_by(icao24) %>%
   fill(callsign)
```

Comment: Thank you. I've run the code and the output results in the entire dataframe. Is there any way to store this in a new dataframe or replace the already existing column?

Comment: @KarthikUppuluri you can just assign `df2 <- df1 %>% ...` to differnt object or same

Comment: I've run the code, and after viewing my new dataframe it seems all blank elements in the column have been substituted with the first element for callsign (which is non-blank) instead of the corresponding surrounding callsign. How can this be specified to R that I need to substitude surrounding elements?

Comment: @KarthikUppuluri that was the code for the first case.  If it is adjacent elements, then the second block of code with `fill` should work